# Issues Querying and Downloading Sentinel-3 OLCI Data with Sentinelsat

Tags: python, geojson, sentinel, sentinelsat, sentinel3

I am working with Sentinel-3 OLCI Level-2 Data Products with the Sentinelsat API and am having issues querying and exceeding my data download quota. Overall, I would like to write a program that accepts a date range and a specific geographic location, then downloads a dataframe of all values in the "Oa04_radiance"-band within the specified dates for that location. This is what I have so far:

```
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI, read_geojson, geojson_to_wkt

from datetime import date

from geojson import Feature, Point, Polygon


api = SentinelAPI('user', 'password', 'https://apihub.copernicus.eu/apihub')

lon = -123.312383

lat = 49.319269

my_point = Point((lon, lat))

footprint = geojson_to_wkt(my_point)

products = api.query(footprint,
                     date=(date(2021, 1, 1), date(2021, 6, 15)),
                     platformname='Sentinel-3',
                     producttype='OL_2_LRR___',
                     cloudcoverpercentage=(0, 80))

products_df = api.to_dataframe(products)

api.download_all(products_df.index)
```

Error Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/t7dej/Desktop/Turbid Time Local/SentSat/SenSat_mdl.py", line 48, in <module>
    api.download_all(products_df_sorted.index)
  File "E:\Software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sentinelsat\sentinel.py", line 723, in download_all
    is_online = not self.trigger_offline_retrieval(pid)
  File "E:\Software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sentinelsat\sentinel.py", line 636, in trigger_offline_retrieval
    raise LTAError(msg, r)
sentinelsat.exceptions.LTAError: HTTP status 403 Forbidden: User quota exceeded: MediaRegulationException : An exception occured while creating a stream: Maximum number of 4 concurrent flows achieved by the user
```

Even when I set my `api.query(limit=1)` I am receiving this error message. The products_df is 173 MB and has a geometry column with a value of :

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((-146.081 -49.2196, -145.768 -48.2668, -145.201 -46.4727, -144.658 -44.6765, -144.135 -42.8782, -143.63 -41.0787, -143.142 -39.2767, -142.667 -37.4733, -142.204 -35.6694, -141.753 -33.863, -141.312 -32.0559, -140.878 -30.2474, -140.453 -28.4377, -140.033 -26.6268, -139.62 -24.8151, -139.211 -23.0024, -138.806 -21.1887, -138.404 -19.3744, -138.006 -17.5593, -137.609 -15.7434, -137.213 -13.927, -136.819 -12.1101, -136.425 -10.2928, -136.031 -8.47512, -135.636 -6.65724, -135.24 -4.83889, -134.843 -3.02078, -134.443 -1.2025, -134.04 0.61575, -133.634 2.43352, -133.224 4.25148, -132.81 6.06894, -132.391 7.88578, -131.965 9.702120000000001, -131.534 11.5179, -131.095 13.3329, -130.649 15.1468, -130.194 16.9598, -129.729 18.7716, -129.253 20.582, -128.767 22.3916, -128.267 24.1992, -127.753 26.0043, -127.224 27.8086, -126.678 29.6103, -126.113 31.4098, -125.527 33.2067, -124.919 35.0007, -124.286 36.7919, -123.624 38.5795, -122.932 40.3637, -122.205 42.1436, -121.44 43.9188, -120.631 45.6892, -119.773 47.4541, -118.861 49.2124, -117.886 50.9639, -116.841 52.7073, -115.714 54.4414, -114.495 56.1652, -113.168 57.8769, -111.717 59.5747, -110.12 61.256, -108.352 62.9179, -106.382 64.5568, -104.173 66.16800000000001, -101.677 67.7456, -98.8378 69.2821, -95.5855 70.7672, -91.83369999999999 72.1889, -87.4884 73.5312, -82.44029999999999 74.7715, -76.5813 75.8849, -69.83199999999999 76.83880000000001, -62.1773 77.59399999999999, -53.7161 78.1165, -44.6976 78.3725, -35.5051 78.3451, -26.5677 78.03619999999999, -18.2457 77.46639999999999, -10.7612 76.6694, -4.18714 75.6829, 3.64587789990069e-15 74.8448206506109, 1.50843 74.5429, 6.41354 73.28100000000001, 10.6367 71.9226, 14.2845 70.4875, 17.4519 68.99160000000001, 20.2206 67.4469, 21.6077 67.77589999999999, 23.0264 68.09050000000001, 24.4837 68.3925, 25.9603 68.679, 27.4944 68.9546, 29.0662 69.2161, 30.6951 69.46680000000001, 32.3417 69.6985, 34.024 69.9145, 35.7316 70.10760000000001, 37.4774 70.2903, 39.2531 70.4558, 41.0752 70.6046, 42.9054 70.7343, 44.7579 70.8455, 46.6297 70.938, 48.5174 71.01139999999999, 50.4176 71.0655, 52.3019 71.10290000000001, 52.0832 72.8877, 51.8771 74.6721, 51.6876 76.4562, 51.5212 78.2398, 51.3914 80.0231, 51.3212 81.80629999999999, 51.3582 83.58880000000001, 51.57959163346614 85.05115000000001, 3.911836325497215e-15 85.05115000000001, -133.5599156744917 85.05115000000001, -133.35 83.92870000000001, -133.276 82.14530000000001, -133.33 80.3614, -133.453 78.57859999999999, -133.611 76.7949, -133.799 75.0104, -134.002 73.226, -134.218 71.4409, -134.445 69.6553, -134.678 67.8693, -134.918 66.0826, -135.163 64.2954, -135.413 62.5074, -135.666 60.719, -135.923 58.93, -136.183 57.1401, -136.447 55.3495, -136.712 53.5582, -136.982 51.7664, -137.253 49.9738, -137.528 48.1799, -137.805 46.3858, -138.085 44.5911, -138.368 42.7954, -138.653 40.9991, -138.942 39.2019, -139.234 37.4039, -139.528 35.6058, -139.826 33.8069, -140.128 32.0072, -140.433 30.207, -140.741 28.4055, -141.054 26.6057, -141.37 24.8042, -141.691 23.0012, -142.016 21.1992, -142.346 19.3968, -142.68 17.5942, -143.02 15.7915, -143.365 13.9887, -143.716 12.1859, -144.073 10.3832, -144.436 8.58104, -144.806 6.77937, -145.183 4.97715, -145.567 3.17639, -145.96 1.37623, -146.361 -0.423407, -146.77 -2.22189, -147.19 -4.01968, -147.62 -5.81594, -148.06 -7.61083, -148.512 -9.40438, -148.976 -11.1962, -149.454 -12.9862, -149.946 -14.7742, -150.453 -16.5599, -150.975 -18.343, -151.516 -20.1234, -152.076 -21.901, -152.655 -23.6751, -153.257 -25.4461, -153.883 -27.2129, -154.534 -28.9754, -155.214 -30.7335, -155.923 -32.487, -156.667 -34.2331, -157.447 -35.9749, -158.267 -37.7106, -159.131 -39.4374, -160.043 -41.1566, -161.008 -42.867, -162.033 -44.5672, -162.604 -45.4664, -161.805 -45.7119, -160.989 -45.9615, -160.165 -46.2051, -159.335 -46.4427, -158.497 -46.6742, -157.652 -46.8994, -156.79 -47.1211, -155.932 -47.3333, -155.068 -47.539, -154.207 -47.742, -153.329 -47.9343, -152.444 -48.1198, -151.538 -48.3011, -150.642 -48.4725, -149.738 -48.6368, -148.842 -48.7908, -147.928 -48.9408, -147.008 -49.0835, -146.081 -49.2196)))
```

I have specified a geojson point object in the products query and am wondering why it is returning such a large multipolygon object in the products_df. I am thinking this is why products_df is so large and my quota is exceeded. Does anyone have any recommendations for this? Also, is it possible to query only the specific band 'Oa04_radiance' before downloading since I do not need any of the other bands from the Sentinel-3 OLCI Level-2 data products.